# window.frames returns only the base window

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access the `window` object of an iframe inserted. When I check `window.frames` in the inspection, it is the base window's window object not the one of the iframe and `window.frames.length` is 1. How do I access window object of iframes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>  
  <body>
      some contents
      <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that one is confusing...

It is [per specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#dom-frames) that it returns the `window` object, just like `self` or `globalThis`, and this is apparently a relic from Netscape.  [<sup>ref</sup>](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/VijG80aFnU8).

The important part for you is that this `window` object has a `.length` property saying how many sub-frames there are, you then can access these subframe's windows using the numeric index.

e.g `window[0]` should return your iframe's window, but in StackSnippet's null-origined iframes, it will just throw an Error.

```js
console.log(window[0]);
```

```html
some contents
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
```